# Files after docker build missing in the image

Tags: windows, docker, iis

i am currently trying to build a windows iis docker image. The Dockerfile is in the folder where the files are that has to get into the docker file. I thought it would be automatically moved in, but i cant find the folder in there.

Is it possible to move the files surrouding the docker file into the docker image?

Thanks!

Comment: Please follow this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-copying-files) to use COPY command move file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy all the files by putting the copy command in your docker file:

```
COPY . .
```